# programmatically query FB ads managers api for purchases

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am writing a PHP script to query some data from FB Ads Manager (business.facebook.com) and display it back to the user.

I need to determine the total # number of "website purchases" (clicked or viewed), using either cURL or facebook/php-ads-sdk.

I have an access token, have completed some basic queries in both cURL and API, so setup and authentication are verified. What I need is the proper API route or cURL to get the required info.

The cURL below works for a single ad, but I am working with 1000s of ads. If I don't find a better way, I may traverse the entire account and request data for each ad each time, but that seems very inefficient. Ideally, I'm looking for one API or cURL with ACCOUNT_ID, DATE_RANGE, and ATTRIBUTION_WINDOWS. (NOTE: I don't even need data per ad, just a total # for the supplied account/date/attribution).

```
//single ad cURL solution
curl -i -G \
-d 'fields=actions,action_values' \
-d 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/<AD_ID>/insights
```

A lot of FB's online docs for Ads/Insight are missing or deprecated, and what's there is sparse. FB support will not help with this at all. Any advice is greatly appreciated!!!